# Хочу изменить цвет дорожки у Switch

Tags: android-studio, xml, android-layout

**Знакомьтесь: это мой Switch!**

[image: Знакомьтесь: это мой Switch!]

Вот его XML код:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/check"
    android:checked="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/param"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/param"/>
```

Я хочу перекрасить его из нежного розового цвета в зелёный. Мне кажется, что так будет красивее. Перерыл много ресурсов в Интернете, но не нашёл ничего полезного.

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Вот тут есть на русском про стилизацию: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/switch.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сам по себе `Switch` подчиняется лишь теме Material Design, предусмотренной разработчиком. Поэтому Google сделал элемент под названием `SwitchCombat`, который охотнее подчиняется требованиям.
Вот как он создается в XML-файле активности:

```
...
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch_compat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="SwitchCompat"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON"
    app:showText="true"/>
...
```

Чтобы задать стиль для `SwitchCombat`, надо, во-первых, создать файл `styles.xml` и поместить в него строки вида:

```
<style name="MySwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="trackTint">@android:color/цвет</item>
</style>
```

И, во-вторых, в самом `SwitchCombat` прописать ссылку на стиль:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    ...
    android:theme="@style/MySwitch" />
```

Также можно изменить стиль для активного/неактивного состояния, цвет полосы передвижения и т. д. Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/switch.php).

P. S. По просьбе ТС добавляю изменение цвета самого ползунка:

```
<style name="MySwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
    <!-- Неактивное состояние -->
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@android:color/цвет</item>
    <!-- Активное состояние -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/цвет</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: @M.Muratov, добавил информацию (в конце ответа).